# Cant trigger message after reloadaction

Tags: node.js, botframework

After I enter "reset", I does not received any message "Welcome Back" and restart the conversation.

```
bot.dialog('reset', [
        function(session) {
         session.send("Welcome Back");
         session.beginDialog('/');

    }]
    )
    .reloadAction('reset', 'Ok, starting over.', {
        matches: /^reset/i,

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reloadAction only works for dialogs that have already been added to the stack. In order to use it correctly, the reloadAction needs to be attached to a dialog that has already been called/used previously.

For example, if a user is responding to a series of user profile questions across multiple dialogs (personal info, then address/previous address, followed by education) and the user types 'reset' while in the education dialog, then the reloadAction would trigger having been attached to the first user profile dialog (that collects personal info). Thus, the user would be brought back to the beginning of the user profile dialogs to start over.

If you are intent on calling a new dialog, then you will likely want to use triggerAction. This **does** clear the dialog stack entirely but also allows you to redirect back to dialog *x*. In this way, you achieve the same result as in your ask with just a little bit of extra code:

```js
bot.dialog('reset', [
    function(session, args, next) {
        session.send("Ok, starting over.");
        next();
    },
    function(session) {
        session.send("Welcome Back");
        session.beginDialog('/');
    }]
).triggerAction({
    matches: /^reset/i
});
```

Hope of help!

Comment: I need to use the reloadAction to clear the existing dialog stack.

Comment: reloadAction DOES NOT clear the stack. It only reloads a previous dialog ALREADY IN THE STACK (read [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/blob/8f47a247ea3c26218d21ca0f485d5cb187a421e7/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L3017)). triggerAction DOES clear the stack and is likely what you are wanting to use (read [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/blob/8f47a247ea3c26218d21ca0f485d5cb187a421e7/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L2994)). Hope of help!